# Get groups of rows that have two columns that are equal in a SQL table

Tags: sql, aggregate

So I screwed up and filled a table with duplicate rows... I have a table something like this  (actually THOUSANDS of somethings like this :-(  ) :

```
id    gname     pname    value 
1     15         13       test 
2     15         13       test 
3     15         13       test
4     18         18       test
5     18         18       test 
6     18         18       test
```

---

This table is only supposed to allow one row of the same gname, pname and value.

So now I need to write some sql that will group all these common rows together and delete them all except ONE!  Argh!

Can anyone help me, STEP ONE, I believe is just to get a statement to return all the groups of duplicates.

** BTW - I know this is totally jacked.  This is a very old system that I inherited and a big client this is using this... so I'm aware of the issues.   I can fix the code that caused this ONCE I get the db back to the way its supposed to be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `id` is unique and auto-incrementing this is easy:

```
DELETE Table
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id)
                  FROM Table
                  GROUP BY gname, pname, value)
```

Do a `SELECT` first, though.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Do a SELECT first'?

Comment: @toddv: Be sure to have a look at the rows that will be deleted, before you execute the delete, is what it means

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.  It uses the RANK function to pull all but the first of each gname/pname/value tuple.

```
DELETE a
FROM _table_ a
JOIN 
(
    SELECT id
        , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY gname, pname, value ORDER BY id ASC) AS r
    FROM _table_
) b
    ON a.id = b.id
    AND b.r > 1
```